# Concurrent file system access with golang in Kubernetes

Tags: multithreading, go, kubernetes, goroutine, smb

A prerequisite to my question is the assumption, that one uses a Kubernetes cluster with multiple pods accessing a file system storage, for example Azure File (ReadWriteMany). According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv) this relies on SMB3 and should be safe for concurrent use.

Within one pod `GO` is used (with the [GIN](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) framework) as the programming language for a server that accesses the the file system. Since requests are handled in parallel using `goroutines` the file system access is concurrent.

Does SMB3 also ensure correctness for concurrent ReadWrites **within** one pod, or do I need to manually manage file system operations with something like a Mutex or a Worker Pool?
More specifically: I want to use [`git2go`](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) which is a `GO` wrapper around `libgit2` written in `C`. According to `libgit2`s [`threading.md`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/main/docs/threading.md) it is not thread safe:

> Unless otherwise specified, libgit2 objects cannot be safely accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

Since `git2go` does not specify otherwise I assume, that different references to the same repository on the file system cannot be used concurrently from different goroutines.

To summarise my question:

- Do network communication protocols (like SMB3) also "make" file system operations thread safe locally?
- If not: how would I ensure thread safe file system access in `GO`? [`lockedfile`](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/lockedfile/) seems to be a good option, but it is also internal.

Comment: I think this is rather difficult to answer unless you're both an expert in libgit2 semantics and SMB3. Can you explain what you want to do with libgit2? `"make" file system operations thread safe locally?` it depends what you're doing with the filesystem and whether you're even trying to change the same files etc. Git makes tons of different filesystem operations that can interfere with each other across threads and pods - no filesystem makes it magically "safe".

Comment: I am using `bare` git repositories (without an index) and I am executing different operations on the structs returned by `git2go`. This structs might refer to the same repository. So it would be possible for two clients to trigger an operation (like a commit) on the same repo at the same time. One of my thoughts was *blocking an entire repo* for any operation. I would do this for example by an operation queue, but this might result in a bottleneck.